# Copy Samsung 3 Contacts to my computer or flash drive?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s

Using windows 7, Samsung galaxy 3 phone contacts do not show on the list. How do i copy all my contacts from my phone to my computer or flash drive?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the [Kies](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/answer/ANS00043326/997389218/) program provided by Samsung.  It's a small utility program that runs on Windows (and Mac).  Kies allows you to manage your phone and its data from a GUI running on Windows.  You'll need to connect your phone to the computer using the usb cable that came with it.

Comment: I connected the phone to the computer using the USB cable that came with it. The Contacts folder does not show.  The phone is SHG-T999L version of Samsung Galaxy S3.

Comment: Did you run the Kies program after connecting the cable?

Comment: @user118996 Contacts don't appear as a folder in Kies. Instead, look in the sidebar for the main application window for them.